# Ruby logger to append mode

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, logging, activesupport

My question is divided in 2 sections

Firstly, 
There are multiple ways to create a loggers (I using ActiveSupport::Logger) which inherit from Logger.

```
# Approach 1
logger = ActiveSupport::Logger.new('test.log') 
logger.info "Test1" # => I see the auto flushing happens in this

# Approach 2
logger = ActiveSupport::Logger.new(File.new('test.log','a'))
logger.info "Test2" ## No auto flushing unless done logger.close
```

So, I don't see a point with approach 2 no auto flushing happen in them.

Why does the auto flushing does not happen in approach 2?

Secondly,

If I happen to **delete my log file** none of above approach(mention above) ever create a **new log** file again and also not log the log message.

What should I do in the situation like this? How does Rails does this? Any clue?

Answer (score 0):

Autoflushing is a property of the `IO` object, not of the `Logger`. `Logger` (via [LogDevice](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.2.3/libdoc/logger/rdoc/Logger/LogDevice.html)) sets `f.sync = true` when it opens the file, so if you want to autoflush to a custom file, you need to do that yourself:

```
> f = File.open('test.log', 'a')
> f.sync = true
> l = ActiveSupport::Logger.new(f)
```

When you delete the file, the `Logger` still has a reference to the old file descriptor, which no longer has a place on disk to write. If you try to `lstat` it, you'll see an error:

```
> f.lstat
Errno::ENOENT: No such file or directory @ rb_file_lstat - test.log
```

If you notice this, you can `reopen` to get a new file on disk:

```
> f.reopen('test.log', 'a')
> f.lstat
#<File::Stat dev=0x1000002, ino=22095609, mode=0100644, nlink=1, uid=501, gid=20, rdev=0x0, size=0, blksize=4096, blocks=0, atime=2016-04-19 08:09:45 -0700, mtime=2016-04-19 08:09:44 -0700, ctime=2016-04-19 08:09:44 -0700, birthtime=2016-04-19 08:09:44 -0700>
```

Comment: Agreed for 1st point I was actually assuming logger to do that for me(`sync') whenever I supplied `file` object as argument. Agreed on the 2nd part as well that is when one delete the file it still hold the reference. what I wanted was from the last part was how to effective log a file even basically write a new file in without few changes in code.